# Get string from sql response after key word

Tags: mysql

I have a big string in one of the rows in my table.

Ex. `The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog.`

I'm trying to get a specific string from a specific location.

Ex. `The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs **flock** by when MTV ax quiz prog.`

I can't use the substring, because the starting index isn't constant.

The one thing that could guide me is, in this case "DJs" because it's always before the string that I need.

EDIT: MySQL 5.5.30

Comment: MySQL has substring_index: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index What SQL software are you running?

Comment: MySQL. Doesn't this require an specific position?

Comment: I'd consider splitting the sentence by spaces with a sequence ID. and in where clause lookup 'DJs' and return ID+1.

Comment: You can use INSTR() in MySQL. The rest will be the same as @Christian4145 suggested as solution.

Answer (score 0):

PATINDEX (with MS SQL) will give you the position of the first ocurrence of the string:

```
  declare @str varchar(max) = 'The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs **flock** by when MTV ax quiz prog.'

  select substring(@str, patindex('%DJs%', @str), len(@str))
```

Comment: Guess should have indicated that I use MySQL 5.5.30, my bad. But I  could replicate it in MySQL. Anyway, having the index, how would I select the "flock"?

Comment: It seems that flock is a single term. If so, just take the substring to the position of the first blanck.